# to prevent deleting a record that there is a relation between two tables

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here's my problem
I have 2 table  `tbl_Person` and `tbl_Job` with a common field (`jobID`) and a relationship **jobId is foreign key in tbl_Person**.
I want to prevent and manage : deleting a record of `tbl_Job` if `jobID` is used in `tbl_Person` with C# and SQL.
theoretically I know that, but I can't Implementation it.actually I need a function type of Boolean in sqlserver with searching in tbl_Person then returns true or false
With thanks :)

Comment: For the SQL-Part: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html or better http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/

Comment: Thanks a lot I gonna see it

Answer (score 0):

You may use foreign key constrains to prevent database inconsistency, see:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

So you have a 1 (job) to n (person) relationship between the tables. The foreign key constraint prevents the deletion of a record on the primary key side (job) as long as there are records on the foreign key side (persons) by default. By default I mean that you **don't** have a `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause.

Do **not** add a `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause if you want to prevent deleting a job as long as there are persons attached to it.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_Person 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_person_job FOREIGN KEY (jobID) 
REFERENCES dbo.tbl_Job (jobID) 
ON DELETE CASCADE --  <-- remove this!
```

If there is already such a clause there, drop the constraint and re-create it without this clause.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_Person DROP CONSTRAINT FK_person_job;

ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_Person 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_person_job FOREIGN KEY (jobID) 
REFERENCES dbo.tbl_Job (jobID);
```